# Inline-Element Float-Right of `div`

Tags: css, dom, containers, css-float, inline

I want to right-align an inline element to the right of a [`div`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.ASP).

I have seen `float="right"` applied on a `span` to right align its position. But, it seems semantically incorrect to me, as floats are supposed to move ["boxes" or block elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) left or right of a [container element](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_containers.asp).

Is my understanding of [Float](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) wrong or is there another way of right-aligning [inline elements](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp) in a [CSS-container](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_containers.asp).

Comment: Another issue that I have using Float on a Span is that we use float:right on a span without specifying a width which again goes against the requirements of a Float. Basically, I want to utilise the stretching property of an inline element as it takes the width of the content which in my case is dynamic. Converting that to a DIV looses that advantage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating an element automatically makes it into a box. (See: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction.htm ) However, there is nothing semantically incorrect about it. Semantics don't dictate what should be displayed as a block and what should be displayed inline--that's one reason we can declare that arbitrarily. (It certainly becomes *messy* when you start taking words out of their order--but I doubt that's what you're talking about here, as I can't imagine a case when you'd want to do that *and* have it remain inline.)

Moreover, if you need to align a bit of inline text independent from the flow of normal text (which is what a float does), you really want to display it as a block anyway. If it's really an inline element, all you need is `text-align:right`--anything you need a float or a position declared on you are already treating as a block element, so there's nothing wrong with declaring it as such.

Comment: but using Float without width is not recommended and in this I want my width to be = content and hence the inline element? So, if my element is a block element with Float, would not having the width specified hurt ?

Comment: @Rajat Not having the width specified means that by default your float will shrink to the size of the longest word. You can use white-space:nowrap to override that behavior--then it will be as wide as your content is. (So be sure to put in a BR if you need it to wrap.)

Answer (score 7):

`float: right` is perfectly okay applied to all elements, block-level or inline it doesn't matter, either semantically or according to the spec (so far as I'm aware).

If you want to right-align something without using `float` then there's the possibility of `margin-right: 90%;` (assuming you know that what it's right-aligned from/against fits into the other 10%.

Or `direction: rtl;` but that never works like I think it should, plus it'd likely complicate things.

`position: absolute; right: 0;` would do as you need (but it'd be removed from the document's flow, and it would be positioned against the first of its parent elements that has a defined `position: relative;` (or at least defined `position`).

You could, possibly, use `text-align: right`, but that seems like such a simple solution that I'm sure you'll have already tried it.

If you could provide a use-case, some code and an indication of your expected end-result we might be able to help you more.